# Create VideoView from a video file that is inside of a Zip File - Android

Tags: android

I have successfully downloaded a `.Zip` file from my server, which is then stored on my tablet.

However, I now want to set `VideoView.setUri()` to one of the files in the `.zip`.

I have `DownloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(referenceId)` showing me that the zip's `Uri` is: `content://downloads/my_downloads/305`.

What I want to do now is take that Uri and feed it into the `VideoView`, without extracting it (if possible).

I have found that you can reference a zip's file via the extension:

`"zip_path_zip_name" + "!/" + filename.ext"`.

So you could call:

`VideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("zipPathAndTitle" + "!/" + "test.mp4""));`

But I'm stuck from the `Uri` of: `content://downloads/my_downloads/305` getting that as a file I can reference, to then set as the VideoView's Uri.

Any help is greatly received.

Comment: Why do you want to set uri of a zip file for VideoView?

Comment: I may not have been as clear as I would have liked. I want to create a VideoView using the video inside a zipped file (which has been downloaded to the tablet).

Answer (score 0):

First, extract the zip file to a specific folder in your storage. You can't use file inside this zip file unless you extract it. Get the path of the extracted file you want in this folder then set it to your VideoView.